# Ruby url regex, 'unless http included' not working

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following method to add http:// to the beginning of a url if its not already present:

```
def smart_url(url)
  unless url[/^http?s:\/\//]
    url = 'http://' + url
  end
end
```

It works only if there is no http(s) included, but when http:// is already included it still adds it and I end up with two of them, and when https:// is already included it returns no url at all!

Have I made a mistake in my regex?

Comment: in addition to the answers, this matches https and htts. You need to put the questionmark after the optional character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-regex solution:

```
def smart_url(url) 
  url.start_with?('http://', 'https://') ? url : 'http://'+url
end
```

the `? :` construct is a short way of writing  `if .. then..else..end`.

Comment: Just needed to switch the then .. else around like: ? url : 'http://'+url . Thanks alot :)

Comment: Oh.. that was sloppy. Editted

Answer (score 3):

You should change the regex to:

```
^https?:\/\/
```

A test [here](http://rubular.com/r/7mrBtsbDzb).

Comment: If I use your above regex, if there is http or https already included the method returns nothing

Comment: It's Ruby normal behaviour. A method in Ruby returns the latest evaluated expression. Just add `url` as a last line.

Comment: I decided to go with the non regex approach but your answer was also correct, thanks